# Are there any shortcut to choose all statements in a cell in MS Excel?

Tags: excel-2010

I want to choose all statements in one cell in MS EXCEL by not using mouse. CTRL+A is not working for this purpose.  İs there any other keybord shortcut for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're editing a cell (you can use F2 to do this), CTRL+SHIFT+<Home> will extend selection from the current position of the cursor to the beginning of the cell.

If the cursor is not at the end of the cell, use CTRL+<End> to move it there.

Comment: Nickolay. Thanks for answer. But, it is not I want to do.  I am mentioning about selection of the statement in one cell. For example.  I write 2 words in cell A4 .  then when I want to choose this two world. I have to use mouse after pressing F2.  But I want a keybord shortcut like CTRL + A.

Comment: I erroneously assumed F2 puts the cursor at the beginning of the cell, it's the other way around -- amended my answer. Other than that I don't see how this is not what you want. I'm not sure why you call the cell contents "statements", but if you hit CTRL+Shift+Home after F2 the entire cell contents will be selected. If that's not what you want, perhaps a screenshot of what you need would help.

Comment: Nickolay sorry it was my fault.. I tried again.. Yes it is working... thanks :)